# Count + List with Futures not working

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, nhibernate

I'm having problems with Futures in Nhibernate 3 and can't realize what's wrong.

The following code (without Futures), works as expected:

```
SessionHandler.DoInTransaction(transaction =>
            {
                var criteria = SessionHandler.Session.CreateCriteria<T>();
                var clonedCriteria = (ICriteria)criteria.Clone();

                var count = criteria
                    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
                    .UniqueResult<Int32>();


                var result = clonedCriteria
                    .SetMaxResults(PageSize)
                    .SetFirstResult(page * PageSize)
                    .List<T>();

                ItemList = result;
                TotalResults = count;
                RecalculatePageCount();
            });
```

SessionHandler just stores a Session for this context, and DoInTransaction is a convenience method:

```
public void DoInTransaction(Action<ITransaction> action)
    {
        using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            action(transaction);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Now, the following code causes GenericAdoException:

```
    SessionHandler.DoInTransaction(transaction =>
            {
                var criteria = SessionHandler.Session.CreateCriteria<T>();
                var clonedCriteria = (ICriteria)criteria.Clone();

                var count = criteria
                    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
                    .FutureValue<Int32>();


                var result = clonedCriteria
                    .SetMaxResults(PageSize)
                    .SetFirstResult(page * PageSize)
                    .Future<T>();

                ItemList = result;
                TotalResults = count.Value;
                RecalculatePageCount();
            });
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2, Npgsql 2.0.11.0 and NHibernate 3.3.1.4000. If that matters, I use Fluent NHibernate for my mappings
Thank you for any advice.

EDIT:
After more research, I found that this error only occurrs after I add an item. At starting, I'm loading data in my form, and it works just fine. I get the exception when I reload the data in my form after adding an item. But it is pretty strange. The item is added correctly. The code for adding or updating items looks like this:

```
if (IsEditing)
                {
                    SessionHandler.DoInTransaction(tx => SessionHandler.Session.Update(CurrentItem));
                }
                else
                {
                    SessionHandler.DoInTransaction(tx => SessionHandler.Session.Save(CurrentItem));
                }
```

What is strange is that I (sometimes, I think) get this exception when I'm raising the PropertyChanged event. I noticed that sometimes the InnerException is different. Sounds like a threading problem, but it is strange that it works without futures. But I'm not using threads for loading the data, just for adding items (hmm, but maybe, because I notify when my items are added, and I load the items in answer to "that message", I think that load would be executed in another thread)

EDIT 2:
The error seems pretty random. Sometimes I get it, sometimes not :S

Comment: What's the inner exception? GenericADOException is just a global database exception wrapper from NHibernate.

Comment: I get NotsupportedException: Backend sent unrecognized response type: \0
I'm also getting DataException in Npgsql

Comment: Based on what you say, the use of treads seem dubious.

Comment: @OskarBerggren I found the cause some minutes ago, and yes, it was multithreading. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the issue.

This may sound stupid, but I think it makes sense. I had to swap these lines:

```
ItemList = result;
TotalResults = count.Value;
```

So they resulted

```
TotalResults = count.Value;
ItemList = result;
```

The problem was, basically, multithreading (I think I didn't mentioned it pretty much in my question, but the randomness of the errors were a bit suspicious). So first, I'll tell you some background so the solution is clearer:

When a new element is added to the database, a message is (globally) sent, so everyone 'interested' can update its elements to reflect the changes. As I'm using MVVM Light, I do it like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new DataReloadSuggested<MyEntityType>(theUpdatedId));
```

I was using Tasks to **add the elements**, so when I clicked on the 'Add' button, something like this was executed:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(CommitCurrentItem);
```

And, inside CommitCurrentItem, I added the item to the database and notified the program that the list was updated (sending the message as mentioned above).

My main form registered to that messages, like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<DataReloadSuggested<T>>(this, true, unused => LoadPage(CurrentPage));
```

Even though the LoadPage function was not creating a different thread manually (at that moment), it was executed in the same thread as the CommitCurrentItem. A Task is not guaranteed to run in a different thread, but in this case it was. LoadPage just called the code that was in the question. My code is guaranteed to raise the PropertyChanged event (from the INotifyPropertyChanged interface) in the UI thread, so when I set the ItemList property (of type IEnumerable), the UI was notified so it shows the new list. So, the UI retrieved the new value of ItemList while (in the other thread), the line `TotalResults = count.Value;` was executing. 
In this case, I guess the query is not executed against the database until I retrieve the first value (the first item in the list or the RowCount). 
Remember that ISession is not thread safe, so this situation was unreliable: the UI thread and the other thread was using the same session at the same time. In my code I'm not sharing the sessions between the ViewModels, and each ViewModel uses the Session with only one thread at the same time, in order to prevent this kind of situations.

So, the final solution was to force the execution of the query in the same thread I was working, so I simply called `count.Value` before setting `ItemList` to `result`.